# Write this function in a FP way

Tags: scala, functional-programming, shortest-path

I have this function that I wrote to basically compute the distance to each node from a source node. Nodes are strings and `neighbours(node)` return the node neighbours.

It works fine, but I'd like something more in the spirit of Scala.

How could I rewrite it? (maybe with recursion?)

```scala
def distanceMap(source: String): Map[String, Int] = {
    val distances = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, Int]
    var batch = List(source)
    var newBatch: List[String] = Nil
    val seen = scala.collection.mutable.Set(source)
    var distance = 1
    while (!batch.isEmpty) {
        newBatch = batch.flatMap(neighbours(_)).filterNot(seen(_))
        for (neighbour <- newBatch) {
            seen.add(neighbour)
            distances(neighbour) = distance
        }
        batch = newBatch
        distance += 1
    }
    distances.toMap
}
```

Comment: Hey, I can't give it a shot at this problem right now, but I have a little snippet that also manipulates graphs in a functional way that may or may not be useful for you :) - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/5ckJvLDQTvyRK1s1d7wZag/1 (given a start and an end it computes all the routes that won't connect them)

Answer (score 2):

Try recursion with accumulators and helper function

```scala
def distanceMap(source: String): Map[String, Int] = {
  def loop(
    distances: Map[String, Int],
    batch: List[String],
    seen: Set[String],
    distance: Int
  ): Map[String, Int] =
    if (batch.isEmpty) distances
    else {
      val newBatch = batch.flatMap(neighbours).filterNot(seen(_))
      loop(
        distances ++ newBatch.map(neighbour => neighbour -> distance),
        newBatch,
        seen ++ newBatch,
        distance + 1
      )
    }

  loop(Map(), List(source), Set(source), 1)
}
```